# Rasperry Pi Stepper Motor

Tags: python

I am new to coding and need to use python for my senior capstone project. I want this code to allow my stepper motor to go up and down so I want to input two values that would allow for this. Additionally I want to add code that will allow the code to run contiunosly and will run when I simply power up the machine

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 

out1 = 13
out2 = 11
out3 = 15
out4 = 12

i=0
positive=0
negative=0
y=0



GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(out1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(out2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(out3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(out4,GPIO.OUT)

print "First calibrate by giving some +ve and -ve values....."


try:
   while(1):
      GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
      GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
      GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
      GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
      x = input()
      if x>0 and x<=400:
          for y in range(x,0,-1):
              if negative==1:
                  if i==7:
                      i=0
                  else:
                      i=i+1
                  y=y+2
                  negative=0
              positive=1
              #print((x+1)-y)
              if i==0:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==1:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==2:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==3:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==4:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==5:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==6:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==7:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              if i==7:
                  i=0
                  continue
              i=i+1


      elif x<0 and x>=-400:
          x=x*-1
          for y in range(x,0,-1):
              if positive==1:
                  if i==0:
                      i=7
                  else:
                      i=i-1
                  y=y+3
                  positive=0
              negative=1
              #print((x+1)-y) 
              if i==0:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==1:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==2:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==3:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==4:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==5:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==6:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==7:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.03)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              if i==0:
                  i=7
                  continue
              i=i-1 


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()'
```

I am able to input values I want and the stepper motor will rotate that value

Comment: Look into [crontab](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md) for scheduling your script to run on boot